# How to sort lines of data with its attribute of date in objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting

I have a text file which contain five lines. I read that files and put them in lines. Like this

```
    char urlOfFile[100] = {0};
    printf("Enter URL Of File: ");
    scanf("%s", urlOfFile);
    NSString *convertedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", urlOfFile];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:convertedString];
    NSString *fileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; 
    NSArray *allLines = [fileContent componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
    for (NSString* line in allLines) {
        NSLog(@"Line contains = %@", line);
    }
```

and the file contains :

Project Description Start date  Category    Responsible Savings amount  Currency    Complexity

4   Decrease production related non-categorized side costs  2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 Dairy   Daisy Milks 11689.322459    EUR Hazardous

5   Stop using Kryptonite in production 2013-04-01 00:00:00.000 Dairy   Clark Kent  NULL    NULL    Moderate

6   Black and white logo paper  2012-06-01 00:00:00.000 Office supplies Clark Kent  4880.199567 EUR Simple

6   Black and white logo paper  2012-06-01 00:00:00.000 Office supplies Clark Kent  4880.199567 EUR Simple

How to sort these lines with respect to given dates in the column of start date, with ascending and descending order and display only one line if the argument is project number.
Any help or clue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Clue #1 - Scan the date in each line of text.

Comment: Seems like csv to me, but the separator is absent? Or it's a space, and clearly not "unique".

Comment: but i get the lines separated with the above code, i can put them each line into array. but how to sort them i would love to know

Comment: It's possible, you can use `NSDataDetector` to find the date on each line, and use a sort on it, but I STRONGLY suggest to fix before the "kind/format of data". It could be really helpful later, if you want for instance to get the "description" of the product, and then create custom objects. SO is not only for "fixing issue", it also guides on best coding behavior/recommendations.

Comment: Hi Larme, any example of code will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Larme But SO is no "write my code" service. And this Q tends to be that way.

Comment: Look for CSV fisrt. Format your data to be compliant to CSV. Then there are plenty of questions about reading CSV, you isolate then eah part including the date. Then there are plenty of questions about sorting array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm betting your data is TAB-delimited (StackOverflow displays tabs as individual spaces).

So...

```
NSString *fileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; 
NSArray *allLines = [fileContent componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
for (NSString* line in allLines) {
    NSLog(@"Line contains = %@", line);

    // split each tab-delimited line into fields
    NSArray *allFields = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"];

    // store the fields in an array of custom class, or core-data, or whatever
    [theData addObject:[MyClass initWithArray:allFields]];
}
```

Then you can sort on the date or whatever other field / criteria you want.